# Combining supplements

Tags: supplements

I take several supplements that are listed to be taken on an empty stomach. Since having an empty stomach all day and taking these one at a time is counterproductive, can I take all of these at one time and still receive the full benefit of each?

Comment: Can you share specific supplements and amounts?

Answer (score 1):

If your supplements are vitamins, it would be good to know if they are fat soluble or water soluble.  Fat soluble vitamins are only absorbed into the body when combined with fat (so would not do a darn thing for you on an empty stomach).